# oEmbed work on localhost but not on distant server

Tags: apache, oembed

I've a trouble with oEmbed integration for YouTube on hosting server. I've a Wordpress site that is exactly the same on my localhost (MAMP 3.0.7.3 on MacOSX with PHP Version 5.6.2) and my distant serveur (LAMP with Apache2 and PHP Version 5.6.17-0+deb8u1).

On the localhost, when I paste an URL from Youtube the frame appear but not on the hosted version, where I've this response : `{"success":false,"data":{"type":"not-embeddable","message":"<code>https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=luvQwgRZ9bo<\/code> n&rsquo;a pas pu \u00eatre int\u00e9gr\u00e9."}}`

The commun troubleshooting (like change theme or disable plugin) have no effect.

Maybe oEmbed need Apache2 mod or dependencies to work ? In this case I having ssh access to this server.

Could you, please, help me?

Comment: In my opinion, the URL you are using is malformed for embedding. Try to use URLs looking like this one: `https://youtu.be/luvQwgRZ9bo`. Also you can try to use non-SSL (change `https` to `http`).

Comment: This has nothing to do with wordpress, the URL in the error seems ok, so the "problem" has to be on youtube side

Comment: Nothing change. Short or long version, SSL or not..

Comment: @MarkKaplun with exactly the same WP site, oEmbed WORK fine on localhost and NOT WORK on distant host. It can't be Youtube side.

Comment: @mthchz, you can't have it both ways, if the sites are identical then the issue is with youtube. If they are not, then the question is pointless as you didn't tell as in what way they are different

Comment: @MarkKaplun same WP (file+DB), same embed URLs, but different server. Tested with YouTube, Vimeo, Soundcloud. With and without SSL. More I've tried with others WP on my localhost and on this serveur the issue is alike. So for the last time, it can't be Youtube... ;)

Comment: then the servers are not identical

Comment: Do you understand that error message? It doesn't seem to be in English.

Comment: @Rarst, is in french and encoded, that mean "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=luvQwgRZ9bo could not be integrate"

Comment: After many week, it's fixed ! It was a missing configuration on the apache hosts file which cause troubles on serveur 'self call'. I've just to add '127.0.0.1 domain.com' in /etc/hosts file and it's work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a missing configuration on the apache hosts file which cause troubles on serveur 'self call'. For exemple, if serveur is using domain.com, I've a timeout when I typing `curl domain.com` with shh.

Adding `127.0.0.1 domain.com` in /etc/hosts file and it's work !